# Does Facebook have a penalty policy for pages advertising on other pages?

Tags: facebook-pages, ads

Recently in Facebook, I've seen some pages [which of course have a lot of subscribers] advertising some other pages in their posts. I've also heard there are some methods in which pages exchange "likes" or sell likes!

Does Facebook penalize or block pages for this kind of advertisement while it has his own plans for advertising pages on side bar? Is it safe to advertise your page using these kind of methods?

Comment: Like black hat SEO, but for Facebook instead... very good question! I looked through Facebook policies, couldn't find anything addressing this, but am not familiar enough with Facebook support pages.